# How to have grails run-app use https by default (without the -https command line option)

Tags: grails

I would like to be able to run

```
grails run-app
```

and have it, by default, use ssl as if I ran

```
grails run-app -https
```

I would like this behavior for a couple reasons.  The most important is that I want the Netbeans IDE grails integration to start up the https connection by default.  But also, running on the command line, I won't have to remember or type the https since I always want that in my development environment.

Answer (score 4):

> The most important is that I want the Netbeans IDE grails integration to start up the https connection by default.

Surely this can be configured within the IDE?

> also, running on the command line, I won't have to remember or type the https since I always want that in my development environment.

If you're using Linux or Mac, I would define an alias

```
alias run-app='grails run-app -https'
```

so you can get the behaviour you want simply by typing `run-app` on the command line. You could similarly achieve this on windows by creating a file `run-app.bat` whose contents are

```
grails run-app -https
```

and put this file in a directory that's on the PATH

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @Don, but neither of those will work for me.  I would think the IDE could configure this, but it cannot.  I can manually run "grails run-app -https" from within the IDE, but I cannot have it use https by default.  I think this may be a shortcoming for Netbeans/Grails integration.  I'd like a better IDE, so maybe it is time to switch.

Comment: You can certainly configure IntelliJ to include the `-https` argument by default

Comment: @is there same in STS /GSTS?

Comment: @Dónal "You can certainly configure IntelliJ to include the -https argument by default" Can you please elaborate on how to do this?

Comment: The problem I see with this solution is that developers who pick up your project won't know that they have to include -https as part of the grails run-app command and the app will appear to fail when they try to run it.